# Vue: How to conditionally render tr in tbody

Tags: vue.js

I have a table body with multiple rows, such as this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to conditionally combine v-if an v-for, to conditionally render one or more additional rows.  The Vue manual says to wrap the v-for in a v-if, such as follows:

```
<div v-if="team.positions != null">
    <my-row v-for="position in team.positions"
                :position="position"
                :key="position.id">
    </my-row>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't put a div in a tbody, or any other element for that matter.  What's the solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In those situations where no element would fit, [**you can use `<template>`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt), like:

```html
<template v-if="team.positions != null">
    <my-row v-for="position in team.positions"
                :position="position"
                :key="position.id">
    </my-row>
</template>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showTwoRows: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td><td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <template v-if="showTwoRows">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td><td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button @click="showTwoRows = !showTwoRows">Toggle two middle rows</button>
</div>
```

Though in that specific example of yours, it doesn't seem needed. Have you tried simply not using the `v-if`:

```html
<my-row v-for="position in team.positions"
            :position="position"
            :key="position.id">
</my-row>
```

Because the `v-for` just won't iterate (without throwing errors) if its value is `undefined`/`null`/`0`/`[]`/`''`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "If I'm being displayed, Vue works!",
    team: {
      positionsU: undefined,
      positionsN: null,
      positionsZ: 0,
      positionsE: [],
      positionsS: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsU"><td>u: {{ position }}</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsN"><td>n: {{ position }}</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsZ"><td>z: {{ position }}</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsE"><td>e: {{ position }}</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsS"><td>s: {{ position }}</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="position in team.positionsF"><td>f: {{ position }}</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one.  You were right on both scores.  I had another bug which was throwing the error...

Comment: The addition of the `template` tags worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-for` and `v-if` on the same tag, however, it works differently to how you'd expect it to.

within the `v-if` you can reference the iterated item since `v-for` is performed before `v-if`

```html
<div v-if="team.positions != null">
    <my-row v-for="position in team.positions" v-if="position"
                :position="position"
                :key="position.id">
    </my-row>
</div>
```

this would still iterate through all `positions` in `team.positions`, and not halt the for loop if the condition in the `v-if` was not met, but rather skip it.

think of it like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
        doTheThing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what the original question is looking for, but I just had a similar issue where I wanted to ignore rendering rows where the price of a item was 0.

I ran into the problem using `v-if` in the `<tr>` containing the `v-for`. I solved it by simply using a `v-show` instead.

So this worked perfectly in my case.

`<tr v-show="item.price !== 0" :key="item._id" v-for="item in items"> ... </tr>`